# Content Table in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my code, but the content of the second `<td>` is located at the bottom of the `<td>`

Here's what I have so far:

**CSS**

```
.TableMarket {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    width: 800px;
    height:800px;
    background-color: #9ca4b5;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.TableMarket td {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="TableMarket" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#00ff90;">
      <img src="images/a.PNG" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:#ff6a00;" >
      <p>
      name....
      family.....
      age....
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a JSFiddle to accompany the post: http://jsfiddle.net/WHFMk/

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i see you have some nice vertical-aligned texts in the table...

Answer (score 2):

So, you want the text to be at the top of the box?

If so, `vertical-align` works;

```
vertical-align: top;
```

If not, can you clarify on the question; it's a little confusing.

http://jsfiddle.net/A7BrT/

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to get the cell content at the top, try this:

```
.TableMarket td {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Comment: @Stella If you're purpose in life is to be modern-standards incompliant yet functional, then alternatively you can always use "valign='top" as an attribute for td in your html.